# copying files from one windows server to another

Tags: windows, wmi, powershell-remoting, microsoft-bits

I have to copy a file from a windows 2008 server to one or more windows 2008 servers. I have accounts on the target machines with enough privileges to let me use powershell remoting and use wmi. The remote machines do not run ftp, ssh or similar file transfer mechanisms. I am not allowed to install software or run new services on the target server. I can run services on the source server.

The file copy action must be initiated from the source server. i.e. I cannot manually logon to the target machines and initiate the copy - though an automated way to do this is acceptable.

Is it possible to use WMI or PowerShell Remoting to push or pull the file from the source to the target ? Is it possible to invoke some sort of built in http client or invoke the BITS service/agent on the remote servers to pull files from the source server ?

Other suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to copy files using the constraints you've been given. Basically, you will need to ensure the source server has a file share that's accessible by the target host. You will then need to follow the process created by Frank White, here on SO, and fully fleshed out and referenced here, though you'll have to translate from VBS to PS1:
[Trying to copy file from one XP PC to another using WMI, since RPC and UNC are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769129/trying-to-copy-file-from-one-xp-pc-to-another-using-wmi-since-rpc-and-unc-are-n)